# Div moves in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a table with two columns. The left column has some content and a widget div that is the only floated element. This div keeps moving to the bottom of the page taking the right column of the table with it when the page loads. Sometimes it moves back when I hover something, it seems to be completely random.

Seems like the IE peek-a-boo bug but not quite. I've tried `position: relative;` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here's the html:

```
<table class="formTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="content_main">
            <h1>header</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content here</td>
                    <td>Content here</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div style="float: left; clear: none; display: block; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); font-weight: normal; font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;Verdana&quot;,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; text-decoration: none; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 10px; height: auto; width: auto; background-image: none; background-color: white; border: 10px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); overflow: auto;" id="widget">
                Content
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="content_right">
            <ul>
                <li>List</li>
                <li>List</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here's the css for the table:

```
.content_right {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 393px;
}
.content_main {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: try using a css reset script such as [yui2 reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Comment: Can't reproduce.. can you change [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wytE/) to reproduce what you experience? Maybe something in the content?

Comment: What docType are you using for your example? Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for me. If you know how to use divs, avoid tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <h1>header</h1>
        <article>Content here</article>
        <article>Content here</article>

        <div id="widget">
            Content
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>List</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
```

Try HTML like this, and use a CSS style sheet instead of the inline blob. Standards are made for a reason. By now all recent browsers support them, eliminating the need for crappy markup and the 'bugs' it causes. See http://www.abookapart.com/ for reading material.